# Unable to connect with CloudKit-JS CONFIGURATION_ERROR

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services, cloudkit-js

I am trying to set up Cloudkit-JS to access an existing Cloudkit database through a web browser. The db itself works fine and I have an iOS app which connects to the db without any problems.

I've generated an API Token in the Cloudkit Dashboard and I've set it to allow any domain. I don't know if its significant but I'm trying to get this working through a local html file. It's not running on a web server.

```js
CloudKit.configure({
    containers: [{
        containerIdentifier: 'iCloud.com.[My App]',
        apiToken: '[API Token]',
        environment: 'development'
    }]
});

var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
```

The call to getDefaultContainer() triggers the following error message in the browser console.

```
    ckErrorCode: CONFIGURATION_ERROR
    extensionErrorCode: undefined
    isCKError: true
    isError: true
    isServerError: true
    isServerExtensionError: true
    message: CONFIGURATION_ERROR: Please configure CloudKit
    name: Error
    reason: CONFIGURATION_ERROR: Please configure CloudKit
    recordName: undefined
    redirectURL: undefined
    retryAfter: undefined
    serverErrorCode: undefined
    subscriptionID: undefined
    uuid: undefined
    zoneID: undefined
]
    getDefaultContainer (cloudkit.js:12:1146)
    Global Code (index.html:29)
```

Any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a rookie error. I was trying to call getDefaultContainer() before the authentication had completed asynchronously.

Comment: Do you have a simple example that shows the proper order of things? I thought `getDefaultContainer()` was needed just to start the authentication process.